# Make variable all lower case in batch without call

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here is a code I found to make a value lower case, but was curious how to do it without the CALL and just use a variable:

```
SET String=Hello, how are you ?
CALL :LoCase String
:LoCase
FOR %%i IN ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i" "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r" "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z") DO CALL SET "%1=%%%1:%%~i%%"
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: You are missing `GOTO :EOF` in between `CALL :LoCase String` and `:LoCase`. Anyway, you don't have to use `call` but you'll need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) then. The loop body could be this then: `SET "String=!String:%%~i!"`

Comment: So the code you are using obviously must be working for you other than what @aschipfl pointed out. But what you should be saying to yourself is how does this existing code actually work.  If you understood how it worked, you would then be able to easily change the code to use it without the `CALL` commands.

Comment: I have a feeling that there are other characters which can be lower cased, not just those with ASCII codes `65` to `90`.

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl, I see why I need delayed expansion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure which call you want to avoid - the one in the for loop or calling the subroutine. But it is possible to ditch both with [macro](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html) and [delayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) which will be executed much faster:

```
@echo off

set locase=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 ( for %%# in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "result=!result:%%#=%%#!") ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set result=

set "string=SOme STrinG "
%locase%%string%

echo %result%
```

Also because of the way how replacement works in batch files you can just list the lower case letters - this will increase the performance also. Probably the code above is the fastest possible way to set string in lowercase only in batch file.

Comment: Nice solution, still feel it's worth adding the extra loop to process  and  return the string to the original variable name

Comment: It requires a minor modification npocmaka, it should be `%locase%%string%`, otherwise you're introducing an additional leading space character! Also, personally, I'd change `for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2` to the slightly shorter `for %%n in (1 2) do if %%n equ 2`, or `for %%n in (1 2) do if %%n==2`, or `for %%n in (1 2) do if %%n gtr 1`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't wish to use Call at all, convert the function to a macro.
Here's a macro that can convert upper or lower

```bat
@ECHO OFF & Setlocal DISABLEDelayedExpansion
(Set \n=^^^
%=Do Not Modify=%
)
(Set LF=^


%=Do Not Modify=%)
 Set CASE=For %%n in (1 2) Do IF %%n==2 (%\n%
  Set "Switch=?"%\n%
  If not "[?]" == "[!Sub!]" (%\n%
   If "!String!" == "" Echo/No args Input. %%Case:?=!Switch!%%!String!!LF! !Usage!%\n%
   For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%G in ("!String!")Do If not "%%~H" == "" (%\n%
    Set "String=%%~H"%\n%
    Set "upper=!Switch:-u=!" ^& If Not "!upper!" == "!switch!" For %%x in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) Do (Set "String=!String:%%x=%%x!")%\n%
    Set "lower=!Switch:-l=!" ^& If Not "!lower!" == "!switch!" For %%x in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) Do (Set "String=!String:%%x=%%x!")%\n%
    Set "supress=!Switch:-s=!" ^& If "!supress!" == "!switch!" Echo/!String!%\n%
    Set "%%~G=!String!"%\n%
   ) Else Echo Missing Arg. %%Case:?=!Switch!%%{%%G}{%%H}!LF! !Usage!%\n%
  ) Else echo/Substring Switch required. %%Case:?=!Switch!%%!String!!LF! !Usage!%\n%
 ) Else Set String=
 Set "SUB=?"
 Set "Usage=Usage: %%CASE:?=[-U|-L]{-S}%%{ReturnVar}{Input String}"
Setlocal ENABLEDelayedExpansion
rem /* usage examples */
 Set /P "iString=String: "
rem /* convert upper */
 %CASE:?=-u%{string.upper}{!iString!}
rem /* convert lower; suppress output */
 %CASE:?=-l -s%{string.lower}{!iString!}
rem /* Demonstrate Macro error handling */
 %CASE:?=-l%
 %CASE%{string.noswitch}{!iString!}
 %CASE:?=-l%{String.false}
 Set string.
```

Comment: Just to demonstrate an alternate path to using macro's for this scenario.

Comment: upvote ,though Is the goto used only to prompt the input forever?

Comment: Loop removed from usage example, script usage modified

Answer (score 2):

It is easy enough to use the ToLower() function in PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows platform, PowerShell is available. It runs on Linux and Mac.

```
SET "STRING=Hello, how are you ?"
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "'%STRING%'.ToLower()"') DO (SET "STRING=%~A")
ECHO STRING is now === %STRING%
```

If this goes into a .bat file script, double the PERCENT character on the FOR loop variable.

```
SET "STRING=Hello, how are you ?"
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "'%STRING%'.ToLower()"') DO (SET "STRING=%%~A")
ECHO STRING is now === %STRING%
```

It will process a string containing a QUOTATION MARK character.

```
C:\src\t>SET "STRING=Now Is ""The Time"
C:\src\t>FOR /F "delims= eol=" %A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "'%STRING%'.ToLower()"') DO (SET "STRING2=%~A")
C:\src\t>(SET "STRING2=now is "the time" )
C:\src\t>SET STRING
STRING=Now Is ""The Time
STRING2=now is "the time
```

If the code is written in PowerShell, it could be:

```
$String = "Hello, how are you?".ToLower()
Write-Output $String
```

Comment: the call powershell version does not work for strings that start with `;`, i suggest `delims=` -> `delims^=^ eol^=`

Comment: Good call, @HackingAddict1337. I made the change. The `FOR /?` documentation does not mention SEMICOLON as a default eol.

Comment: Good. Except now you have another problem, because `FOR /F "delims= eol="` does not disable `eol` but sets `eol` to `"`, whereas `delims^=^ eol^=` is foolproof.

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 - It does not seem to have a problem using `eol="`. Of course, there are frequently problems with text containing QUOTATION MARK characters in cmd. If that is needed, cmd is probably not the right tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

[`DIR /L`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php) works for all ***filenames***, even [***Unicode like ÁCCÉNTS***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205638).

The macro `$lower` is defined by:

```
set ^"$lower=(dir/l/b/o-d "%TEMP%"^|"%ComSpec%" /v/c"set/plower=&echo(!lower!") 9^>\\?\"%TEMP%"\"
```

where `DELAYEDEXPANSION` must be ***DISABLED***.

---

A demonstration script:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
====SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


set "PATH="
set "DPATH="
set "PATHEXT=;"
set ^"$lower=(dir/l/b/o-d "%TEMP%"^|"%ComSpec%" /v/c"set/plower=&echo(!lower!") 9^>\\?\"%TEMP%"\"


echo START: %time%
%$lower%"Hello, how are you"
%$lower%"I print a string (VALID FILENAME) in lower case"
%$lower%"ABCDEFGHIIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
%$lower%"GreekΘ&Áccents work"
%$lower%"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"
%$lower%"µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİİĲĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŉŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸŹŻŽ"
%$lower%"   SPA        CES "
%$lower%"EXCLAMS!!!"
%$lower%";SEMICOLONS all work"
%$lower%"SADLY ILLEGAL FILENAMES DON'T"
%$lower%"\/:*?<>|"
echo END: %time%
```